Multi-monitor and multi-workspace mess in 24.04
I have a desktop setup with 3 monitors and I make heavy use of multiple workspaces, where I organize the opened programs/windows by personal or work interests and so on; in each workspace, most important stuff stays in the middle monitor and other stuff goes to one of the side monitors. If I reboot the machine and open the same programs, the system 'remembers' the workspace and monitor of all windows. If one of the monitors is disconnected, the system rearrange the windows of the disconnected monitor in the other 2 and if the monitor is connected again, the system reorganizes the previous 3-monitor arrangement (sort of but OK).
I recently installed a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 (Gnome, Wayland, Nvidia card and proprietary driver), and most of the times the behavior of the arrangement when disconnecting/connecting any monitor is the same as before, but not rarely it happens to simply forget everything. ALL windows of ALL workspaces comes to the 1st workspace and to the middle monitor and I have to organize everything from the scratch again. You can imagine how annoying this is.

EDIT: my Settings -> Multitasking configuration is:

Workspaces: "Fixed Number: 5"
Multi-Monitor: "Workspaces on all displays"
App Switching: "Include apps from all workspaces" and "Include apps from all monitors"


My 1st question is: where is the information of the windows arrangement stored? Maybe I can 'scriptize' the arrangement of 'known' programs/windows.
2nd question: where is the code to manage this arrangement? Maybe I can contribute to solve this issue.

You mention a multi-desktop install, but only mention a single desktop being GNOME. Window Management is largely handled by the Window Manager, and in my case as I'm also using a multi-desktop install and I'm using Xfce with the Xfwm4 WM & also LXQt with the same Xfwm4 WM those are managed by the same program, but as I'm currently logged into the GNOME desktop its using Mutter to handle those functions. I have five displays connected currently; but only 4 are currently on, and turning displays ON/OFF doesn't impact window placement (all desktops are the same in this regard in my experience)'

I've setup my monitors in each desktop individually as I want, eg. I've told LXQt (and my selected WM being Xfwm4) how I want displays setup, then I did the same in the Xfce Desktop (it has its own configs, as Xfwm4 is a window manager), then repeated the process for my other desktops which include my currently used GNOME session.  They don't share configs; each desktop has its own configs (I've made LXQt & Xfce share the same window manager only; that's mostly due to an issue with my monitor setup that triggers an issue with Openbox I prefer to avoid).

@guiverc all my "desktops" are Gnome. Maybe I should call it workspaces and not desktops. It's only one computer with 3 monitors and N desktops/workspaces under only one window manager.

What happens when you try manually dragging the monitors into a new arrangement by following the instructions in this accepted answer?

@karel this is not happening in my configuration.
